# Patterns for custom view initialization compatible with layout preview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm wondering if there are any good design pattern for initializing custom views (for example passing in a model/renderer). In particular I'm interested in patterns that allow for Android Studio layout preview to work (or something like [mirror](http://jimulabs.com/) to work).

For example take a simple game structure:

**layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout>
  <com.package.GameSurface>
</LinearLayout>
```

**GameSurface.java**

```
public class GameSurface extends View {

    int mComputedParam;

    Renderer mRenderer;
    GameState mGameState;

    public PlaySurface(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PlaySurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    // What are other ways of achieving this?
    public void init(GameState gameState, Renderer renderer) {
        mGameState = gameState;
        mRenderer = renderer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int newWidth, int newHeight, int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
        // Game state is used to calculate some layout/size/render information on the fly
        mComputedParam = (newWidth - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight()) / mGameState.level();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // Render can be swapped out based on level or user settings, etc
        mRenderer.draw();
    }

}
```

Something like this will crash the Android studio layout preview since onDraw and onSizeChanged both throw null pointer exceptions if called without the `init()`.

Would there be some other approach that makes this possible? Some ideas off the top of my head:

- Have a default renderer and model to fallback to in the layout preview. If this is a preferred solution, is there a way to detect that my code is being run in the layout preview?
- Have an option to choose the renderer via some sort of XML attribute, e.g. `custom:renderer="@values/default_renderer"` and then specify one for layout preview view `tools:renderer="@values/preview_renderer"`. It seems like there might [not be good support for this](http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes) (see Limitations section). This also might not work in some situations where instantiating the renderer couldn't easily be done in a static/preview context.
- Perhaps there's a way to run some setup code in the layout preview that I've overlooked?